# Does docker container retain file revision history?

Tags: docker

Consider following scenario:

- create file1.txt inside the container
- docker commit
- rm file1.txt inside the container
- docker commit

Will docker retain contents of file1.txt in latest image?

Comment: Each commit produces a new layer. Older layers are immutable. So yes, file1.txt is present in the older layer.

Comment: Thanks, @JonathonReinhart ! Is it possible to recover or manage older layers anyhow?